# Databases - What is the difference between a local logical database model and a global one?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, global, local

So I have these two school tasks/questions:

**a) Describe the purpose of merging data models. Discuss the difference between local
logical data model and global logical data model.**

**b) Create and validate the local logical data models for local conceptual data models in
Figure1.**

[image]

I have never ever once heard about the term "local and global logical data models" during my course so this question really suprised me and I really have no idea what the difference is (nor have I found anything regarding "database merging" and why you do it). I have searched in my school books and on the internet and have found absolutely nothing regarding this. Maybe I am just bad at googling...

Can you please provide me with an easy to understand source for this or even better, explain this to me and help me answer these questions?

Thanks!

Comment: I have worked with databases for more than 20 years and I never heard these terms before today either. At a guess, I would try looking at replication.

Comment: @HLGEM I would assume that these expressions are specific to the case study. Something like mobile app (local database) and server (global database) development.

Comment: I've dealt with databases for a quarter of a century; these are new terms to me.  Sounds like your professor is having fun with terminology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of data modelling methodologies about. Data modellers are very fond of inventing new ones. I guess you are referring to Connolly and Begg's method and they have a book called *Database Systems - A Practical Approach*.

> A local logical data model represents one or more but not all user
>   views of a database whereas global logical data model represents all
>   user views of a database.

Comment: That is supposed to be less cryptic??